# Rich Textbox Images Not Visible On Salesforce SITE

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, images

I have created one VF page and used some images on it, these images are stored on records richtext box field, preview of VF page showing everything correct .
but Now when I created the SITE for this visual force page and opening my page on SITE it is not showing many Images.And In place of Images showing below error message. Please share some ideas to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution of it, the issue was because of the permissions on site, field permission was missing.